Headless clasp log in
I have a template repository I use for whenever I want to start a Google Apps Scripts project. I create a repository from that template and then start a new Codespace instance which sets up the development environment I need. One of the first things I do is npx clasp login and then log in via the browser UI. This deposits default credentials at /home/codespace/.clasprc.json.
If I return to this exact codespace instance, I of course do not need to log in again. However, if I create a new instance, I must repeat this process. Is there anyway to set up my codespace devcontainer so that anytime a new codespace instance is created, I can log in to clasp without needing to go through the UI?
